# Austrian landing pages aren't working as expected

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.4, language, multilingual

Evening all,

I'm having issues setting up a landing page for Austrian website visitors to a .com website with multiple languages installed (one of which is already german using a /de url)

I have the language pack installed for German, I have setup a de and at content language and setup a default de and at menu item. When i navigate to the .com/at url it always keeps the current language url then adds the at such as .com/fr/at or .com/de/at instead of .com/at and then gives me an obvious 404 error.

I'm using Joomla! 3.4.8 and the core language manager and menu manager.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 1):

Hello @AndySmith and welcome to JSE.

After being in her 4th generation, Joomla is just mature enough not to make such weird errors on her own. That being said I am almost certain that some  extension is causing this problem of "Double language code in URL with SEF giving 404s".

In the matter of fact, I've had similar problems few years back with J2.5, which turned out to be caused by 'Nice Ajax Poll module'. I have shared that at Joomla forum in topic [Double language code in URL - SEF gives 404](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=617&t=618807&start=30), and it turned out there were other extensions responsible for similar problems (ChronoForms, Extrawatch, etc...). I know I should list excerpt from this post in case the link goes down, but it's just not possible in this case.

I obviously have no exact answer to your problem, just 'opening your eyes' to the possibility that some extension you have (either component, module or plugin) might have caused this. You will have to test it by disabling them one by one. Good luck.